# font-awesome with asp.net mvc and ie11/Safari only SOME icons don't work

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, safari, font-awesome

I've found many resources on what to do if NONE of the font-awesome icons are working, but I have an issue where only SOME of the icons are missing, and only on IE and Safari.

It appears to be affecting all of the icons that have a "content" value of "\f20d" and above...

that is, if I select the class for icon "fa-meanpath" (which has a content value of \f20c) the icon is visible.

if I change it to "fa-buysellads" (which has a content value of \f20d) the icon does not show, nor does any icon with a value higher. The space is completely blank (not seeing the square icon or anything else, just blank).

values LOWER than f20c appear to work fine...

I checked the list of icons here: http://fontawesome.io/icons/

and those same icons DO work on that page in IE and safari, but on my site, only in IE and safari (including iphone), the icons with that value and above simply do not render.

what are some strategies I can use to troubleshoot this strange problem?

Comment: it seems this is also a problem with safari, so it's not just IE, updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but with Firefox (on Linux Mint) when I upgraded from Font Awesome 4.2 to 4.5. What helped was clearing the Firefox cache. The problem didn't occur in Google Chrome.