# I am unable to use <i class="fa fa-percent"></i> from Fontawesome

Tags: font-awesome

The code  is not returning any results on my website. All other icons seem to work fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of font-awesome are you using? It was added in newer versions: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/1292

Comment: Also: what browser are you using? (If you're using IE11, it would be another instance of this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34146055/font-awesome-with-asp-net-mvc-and-ie11-only-some-icons-dont-work )

Comment: I'm using a recent version of Chrome and the code straight off the fontawesome website.

Answer (score 3):

THE FIX IS TO USE THEIR CDN:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Or if you want to use a css on your drive then copy their CSS into the one you have on your drive. The online one contains

```
  https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css

.fa-percent:before {
      content: "\f295";
    }
```

PROBLEM DESCRIPTION:
I had this problem when I got FontAwesome from NuGet
THERE IS MISSING CSS in FONT AWESOME from NuGet
It is Feb 10 2016 and I just got the font awesome from

Given:

```
<span class="input-group-addon">
<input name="propertyTaxMethod" type="radio" checked /> 
<i class="fa fa-percent"></i>
<input name="propertyTaxMethod" type="radio" /> 
<i class="fa fa-usd"></i>
</span>
```

in the font awesome css I can find  "font-awesome.css"

```
.fa-usd:before {
  content: "\f155";
 }
```

Whoever I can't find the css for percent
There must be something similar to:

.fa-percent:before {
      content: "\xxxxx"; some code
     }

but it is not there.

I hope they fix this bug soon.
Font Awesome is AWESOME!